# np.arange creates a null value matrix on resizing

Tags: python, numpy

The following is the code that I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
animals = DataFrame(np.arange(16).resize(4, 4), columns=['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], index=['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Mouse'])
print(animals)
```

The output I get for this is:

```
         W    X    Y    Z
Dog    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
Cat    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
Bird   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
Mouse  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

The output that I expect is:

```
         W    X    Y    Z
Dog      0    1    2    3
Cat      4    5    6    7
Bird     8    9   10   11
Mouse    12   13   14   15
```

However, if I run just:

```
print(np.arange(16))
```

the output I get is:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
import pandas as pd
animals = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), columns=['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], index=['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Mouse'])
print(animals)
```

or use [numpy.resize()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html)

```
np.resize(np.arange(16),(4, 4))
```

using resize you need to pass the array as an argument

```
import pandas as pd
animals = pd.DataFrame(np.resize(np.arange(16),(4, 4)), columns=['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], index=['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Mouse'])
print(animals)
```

[ndarray.resize()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html) will do inplace operation. So precompute the size and then create a dataframe

```
a=np.arange(16)
a.resize(4,4)
import pandas as pd
animals = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], index=['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Mouse'])
print(animals)
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs for [resize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html):  "Change shape and size of array in-place."
Thus, your call to `resize` returns `None`.

You want `reshape`.  As in `np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer above, [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) for `resize`:

> ```
> ndarray.resize(new_shape, refcheck=True)
> ```
>
> Change shape and size of array in-place.

Therefore, unlike `reshape`, `resize` doesn't create a new array. In fact `np.arange(16).resize(4, 4)` yields `None`, which is why you get the `Nan` values.

Using `reshape` returns a new array:

> ```
>  ndarray.reshape(shape, order='C')
> ```
>
> Returns an array containing the same data with a new shape

.